# MySQL Index for timestamp not improving performance

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table with 350,000, there are 240,000 records in the result of the following query

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `data`
    where `block_id` = 6726
      and created_at > '2000-01-01 00:00:00'
      and created_at < '2199-01-01 00:00:00'
```

This is averaging at about 2 to 3 seconds.

Whereas

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `data` where `block_id` = 6726
```

is averaging at about .05 seconds.

I have tried putting an index on just `created_at`, and also tried putting a combined one for `created_at` and `block_id` but nothing has made a difference.

Do you know why the performance is not improving with the index on the timestamp column? Is it related to the fact that I am using the > and  < ?

Comment: as long as wee don't know nothing about your table and indexes, and also you need to post a EXCPLAIN of both queries, but my guess is that you haven't a index on (block_id,created_at ) and the explain will show a full table scan

Comment: Do you even have any data older than 2000 or later than 2199?  My guess is that your count query is involving most/all of the underlying table, hence MySQL is foregoing with using any index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using a range on the date field (`created_at`), the second part of the combined index is not used.
I would recommend to make the combine index in the reverse order `(block_id, created_at)`.

Then compare the Query Execution Plan (`EXPLAIN <and the query>`).